# JavaScript TypedArray mixing types

Tags: javascript, webgl, typed-arrays

I'm trying to use WebGL and would like to mix some different types into one buffer of bytes. I understand TypedArrays serve this purpose but it's not clear if I can mix types with them (OpenGL vertex data is often floats mixed with unsigned bytes or integers).

In my test I want to pack 2 floats into a `UInt8Array` using `set()`, but it appears to just place the 2 floats into the first 2 elements of the `UInt8Array`. I would expect this to fill the array of course since we have 8 bytes of data.

Is there anyway to achieve this in JavaScript or do I need to keep all my vertex data as floats?

```
src = new Float32Array(2); // 2 elements = 8 bytes
src[0] = 100;
src[1] = 200;

dest = new UInt8Array(8); // 8 elements = 8 bytes
dest.set(src, 0); // insert src at offset 0

dest = 100,200,0,0,0,0,0,0 (only the first 2 bytes are set)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can mix types by making different views on the same buffer.

```js
const asFloats = new Float32Array(2);
// create a uint8 view to the same buffer as the float32array
const asBytes = new Uint8Array(asFloats.buffer);

console.log(asFloats);
asBytes[3] = 123;
console.log(asFloats);
```

The way TypeArrays really work is there is something called an `ArrayBuffer` which is a certain number of bytes long. To view the bytes you need an `ArrayBufferView` of which there are various types `Int8Array`, `Uint8Array`, `Int16Array`, `Uint16Array`, `Int32Array`, `Uint32Array`, `Float32Array`, `Float64Array`.

You can create the `ArrayBuffer` from scratch.

```js
const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(8);
const asFloats = new Float32Array(buffer);
asFloats[0] = 1.23;
asFloats[1] = 4.56;
console.log(asFloats);
```

Or you can do the more normal thing which is to create an `ArrayBufferView` of a specific type and it will create both the `ArrayBufferView` of that type **and** create the `ArrayBuffer` for it as well if you don't pass one into the constructor. You can then access that buffer from `someArrayBufferView.buffer` as shown in the first example above.

You can also assign a view an offset in the `ArrayBuffer` and a length to make it smaller than the `ArrayBuffer`. Example:

```js
// make a 16byte ArrayBuffer and a Uint8Array (ArrayBufferView)
const asUint8 = new Uint8Array(16);

// make a 1 float long view in the same buffer
// that starts at byte 4 in that buffer
const byteOffset = 4;
const length = 1;  // 1 float32
const asFloat = new Float32Array(asUint8.buffer, byteOffset, length);

// show the buffer is all 0s
console.log(asUint8);

// set the float
asFloat[0] = 12345.6789

// show the buffer is affected at byte 4
console.log(asUint8);

// set a float out of range of its length
asFloat[1] = -12345.6789;  // this is effectively a no-op

// show the buffer is NOT affected at byte 8
console.log(asUint8);
```

So if you want to for example mix float positions and Uint8 colors for WebGL you might do something like

```js
// we're going to have
// X,Y,Z,R,G,B,A, X,Y,Z,R,G,B,A, X,Y,Z,R,G,B,A, 
// where X,Y,Z are float32
// and R,G,B,A are uint8

const sizeOfVertex = 3 * 4 + 4 * 1;  // 3 float32s + 4 bytes
const numVerts = 3;
const asBytes = new Uint8Array(numVerts * sizeOfVertex);
const asFloats = new Float32Array(asBytes.buffer);

// set the positions and colors
const positions = [
  -1,  1, 0,
   0, -1, 0,
   1,  1, 0,
];
const colors = [
   255, 0, 0, 255,
   0, 255, 0, 255,
   0, 0, 255, 255,
];
{
  const numComponents = 3;
  const offset = 0;  // in float32s
  const stride = 4;  // in float32s
  copyToArray(positions, numComponents, offset, stride, asFloats);
}
{
  const numComponents = 4;
  const offset = 12;  // in bytes
  const stride = 16;  // in bytes
  copyToArray(colors, numComponents, offset, stride, asBytes);
}

console.log(asBytes);
console.log(asFloats);

function copyToArray(src, numComponents, offset, stride, dst) {
  const strideDiff = stride - numComponents;
  let srcNdx = 0;
  let dstNdx = offset;
  const numElements = src.length / numComponents;
  if (numElements % 1) {
    throw new Error("src does not have an even number of elements");
  }
  for (let elem = 0; elem < numElements; ++elem) {
    for(let component = 0; component < numComponents; ++component) {
      dst[dstNdx++] = src[srcNdx++];
    }
    dstNdx += strideDiff;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, I really appreciate it. I don't fully understand your copyToArray() function but if you have 2 arrays where an element is either a float or a byte and those both map to UInt8Array then it should work. I'll try this tomorrow when I have some time.

Comment: Late, but wouldn’t you allocate / deallocate memory every time you created a view? (Are those on the heap?) This wouldn’t be very good when filling a vertex buffer per-frame. You’d have to allocate offset typed arrays for practically every array access! How does this work?

Comment: I'm not sure your point. You don't have to allocate views. Do the math or pre-create views. Why do you need a new view every frame?